# A function to print S3 data to HTML using Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I had a correct connection to S3, because I am able to upload a PDF file to Amazon S3, but I can't display the S3 data into a Django template.

My expected result is when I open the page to view a PDF that I uploaded to Amazon S3, it should show all the PDFs that I have uploaded.
But right now nothing is shown in the Django template.

Following is my code:

`models.py`

```
class PDFDocument(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs/')
```

`urls.py`

```
path('display-pdf/<str:file_key>/', views.DisplayPDFView, name='display_pdf'),
```

`view.py`

```
class DisplayPDFView(View):
    def get(self, request, file_key, *args, **kwargs):
        print(s3)
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    
        try:
            print('ds')
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
            pdf_content = response['Body'].read()
            print(response)
            # Set the appropriate content type for PDF
            response = HttpResponse(pdf_content, content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="{file_key}"'

            return response

        except s3.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
            return HttpResponse('PDF not found.', status=404)
        except:
            print("error")
```

`viewCVpage.html`

```
{% for pdf_document in pdf_documents %}
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="card" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <!-- Display the PDF using an object tag -->
                                    <object data="{{ pdf_document.pdf_file.url }}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
                                        <p>Unable to display PDF. Please <a href="{{ pdf_document.pdf_file.url }}">download the PDF</a> instead.</p>
                                    </object>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 can be quite complex when it comes down to permission;

> I had a correct connection to S3, because I am able to upload a PDF
> file to Amazon S3

The fact that you can upload, doesn't mean that you are able to **read**, and vice versa.

The first thing that I would suggest is to check whether you are able to list items from the specific S3 bucket. And if so, check what the output is.

Comment: i had check my permission, all permission had granted, so i can read and write too.

Answer (score 0):

Great, looking at how you set up the s3 client, it looks like there is something missing. You might need to add your **aws_access_key_id** && **aws_secret_access_key**. Something like this:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)
```